# unity c# for ... while ..the code crushes ,counting time upon user keypress and user key up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am doing a key press and count time 1 second to 3 seconds and the object will increase its speed upon how long you press the key and as for key up i am doing when user have let up the key , the object will drop its top speed to zero, not instantly , slowly.

```
public class PlayerMoment : MonoBehaviour

{
private float _maxTime = 3f;
private float i = 0f;
private float _jumpForce = 5.0f;
private float _right = 1f;
private float _left = -1f;
private float _time = 0f;
private float _endTime = 1f;
private Rigidbody2D _ridgi;
private bool _released = false;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    _ridgi = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    
}

void Update()
{
    StartCoroutine("TimeInCrease");
}


IEnumerator TimeInCrease()
{
```

get the input axis

```
    float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    _time += 1f;
```

while _time bigger than one second and if key press a and if axis is less than -0.1
_left will decrease 10f continuesly

```
 while(_time >= 1f)
{
 if (Input.GetKey("a"))
 {
  if (move <= -0.1f)
 {
_left -= 10f;
  }
  }
```

if user key up at 3seconds or 2 seconds or 1 second
will start counting time in decrease
if time equals zero will stopcoroutine to stop time decrease

```
        if(Input.GetKeyup("a") && _time >= 3f || _time >= 2f || _time >= 1f)
        {
            StartCoroutine("TimeDecrease");

            if(_time == 0f)
            {
                StopCoroutine("TimeDecrease");
                break;
            }
           
        }
        _ridgi.velocity = new Vector2(_left * Time.deltaTime, _ridgi.velocity.y);
    }
    
   
   
   
    


  }


 IEnumerator TimeDecrease()
{
    Debug.Log("timeDecrease fires");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
    _time -= 1f;
```

every 0.3 second will decrease_time value
if _time reached bigger than 3second or 2 second or 1 second
will stop to increase time

```
 if(_time >= 3f || _time >= 2f || _time >= 1f)
    {
        StopCoroutine("TimeInCrease");
    }        
    
    
}
}
```

Comment: Please clean up the code formatting and remove the excess whitespace. Also, what is the question?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
public Rigidbody rb
```

and then when you want it to change velocity:

```
rb.AddForce(direction * force, ForceMode.VelocityChange)
```

That should do it, though you might want to add in a `Time.timeDeltaTime` depending on where you're calling this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("a")
    {
        rb.AddForce(direction * force * Time.timedeltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange)
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("a")
    {
        rb.AddForce(-direction * force * Time.timedeltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange)
    }
}
```

This will, as described, gradually accelerate.